# How to test a ref condition in perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, ref

G'Day,

I'm trying to unit test a function that uses a statement like:

```
unless($this->_doc_type eq ref($this->_doc_instance)) {
    # Do something
}
```

No matter how I mock my objects, you can't seem to fool ref(). How should I go about testing this?

- have a private `ref()` function that calls the `CORE::ref()`?
- try and override `CORE::ref` in my unit tests?
- ???

Comment: I guess you're trying to find out if the classname in _doc_type is the same as the class of _doc_instance, in which case you might want, I think, to test using ->isa() instead.

Comment: I want to make sure it is the exact class, so a `Ford` doc should enter the unless condition, even if the doctype is `Car` and `Ford` isa `Car`, if that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 3):

In the bad old days, we had code of the form

```
switch (item->type) {
  case FOO:
    do_foo(item);
    break;

  case BAR:
    do_bar(item);
    break;

  default:
    handle_unknown_type(item->type, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    break;
}
```

This pattern of explicitly inspecting the types of items and then branching off to different functions was repeated many times across the the system's source.

When it came time to add a new type `BAZ` to the mix, that meant going back and touching every single `switch`, `if`/`else` chain, or any other conditional involving `item->type`.

This was a big pain.

Object-oriented languages absorb this pattern so the programmer doesn't have to reimplement it all over the place and doesn't have to waste mental resources on this low-level plumbing. When purportedly object-oriented code yearns for the bad old days, as in

```
unless ($this->_doc_type eq ref($this->_doc_instance)) { ... }
```

it's a strong code smell.

My first suggestion is to redesign the production code. What happens inside the conditional? What is the intent of that code?

I assume you've been using mocks for `_doc_instance`. To get test support in place before refactoring the code, I'd look at how to change the value returned from `_doc_type`, which I also assume isn't a simple getter. Not knowing anything else about the context, one approach is to create a testing subclass.

Say the class you're testing is `My::Container`. If you can get away with a fake document for this particular test (one that has only the superficial appearance of a real document), write code along the lines of

```
package Test::My::Container_Canned_Type;

use base 'My::Container';

sub _doc_type { "Test::Fake::Document" }

1;
```

and then in your test, use it as in

```
my $doc = bless {} => "Test::Fake::Document";
my $c   = Test::My::Container_Canned_Type->new($doc, ...);
```

If I've guessed wrong about the structure of your code, please provide more context so we can give you more helpful suggestions!

Finding yourself in this difficult spot is a good lesson why writing tests *first* is helpful. By design, you eliminate the cases where you're scratching your head and wondering how to test a strange implementation.

### Summary

- No, don't try to modify how `ref` works.
- To the extent possible, eliminate uses of `ref` in your production code.

Comment: Thank you for the very thoughtful answer. As it turns out, `doctype` is a simple accessor :)

Comment: @Gaurav Hm, I'm having a tough time imagining your implementation. If you edit your question to provide a sketch of your high-level intent for the class you're testing and the relationship between `_doc_instance` and `_doc_type`, we'll be able to give you specific, helpful suggestions.